# Correct Date to appear in JSpinner and data formatted correctly to insert to database

Tags: java, sqlite, date, calendar, spinner

I am making a employee scheduling program for a school project.  The employee will be able to make their availability on a weekly basis. I am having trouble making a JSpinner show the date for a Monday of each week.  Also, when the user clicks up or down on the arrows, I would like it to only cycle for the dates of upcoming or prior Mondays.  When inserting the data into a database i would like the start and finish times of each day to be in Military time.  For the week, i would like it to just be the number of the week of the year. When it is inserted into the database, the week is a primary key and should stay constant with the same week, i.e. two employees should be able to create availability for week 5. The employee ID is also a primary and foreign key. The weekID in the database is being created in ascending order i.e. 1,2,3. Start and End times are being shown  as this: Mon Nov 30 09:19:29 CST 2015 when I want it to just show as 09:19.

here is the code for the week spinner:

```
    Date datef = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);




    SpinnerDateModel ehm = new SpinnerDateModel(datef, null, null,     

    c.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
weekOf = new javax.swing.JSpinner(ehm);
JSpinner.DateEditor wo = new JSpinner.DateEditor(weekOf,"MM/dd/yyyy");
weekOf.setEditor(wo);
weekOf.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel());
```

The code for the time spinner is as follows(the times show correctly in these spinners, but just the output isn't correct)

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
monStart = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor ms = new JSpinner.DateEditor(monStart,"H:mm");
monStart.setEditor(ms);
monStart.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel());
```

That is how i have the code set for all of the time selectors, with different variables obviously.

here is the code for the action performed:

```
 public void btnAvailUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnAvailUpdateActionPerformed
        Date weekID = (Date) weekOf.getValue();
        Date mstart = (Date) monStart.getValue();
        Date mend = (Date) monEnd.getValue();
        Date tstart = (Date) tuesStart.getValue();
        Date tend = (Date) tuesEnd.getValue();
        Date wstart = (Date) wedStart.getValue();
        Date wend = (Date) wedEnd.getValue();
        Date thstart = (Date) thursStart.getValue();
        Date thend = (Date) thursEnd.getValue();
        Date fstart = (Date) friStart.getValue();
        Date fend = (Date) friEnd.getValue();


        try {
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Availability (Week_ID, Employee_ID, monStart, monFinish, tuesStart, tuesFinish, wedStart, wedFinish, thursStart, thursFinish, friStart, friFinish) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st.setString(1, String.valueOf(weekID));
            st.setInt(2, loginScreen.dbid);
            st.setString(3, String.valueOf(mstart));
            st.setString(4, String.valueOf(mend));
            st.setString(5, String.valueOf(tstart));
            st.setString(6, String.valueOf(tend));
            st.setString(7, String.valueOf(wstart));
            st.setString(8, String.valueOf(wend));
            st.setString(9, String.valueOf(thstart));
            st.setString(10, String.valueOf(thend));
            st.setString(11, String.valueOf(fstart));
            st.setString(12, String.valueOf(fend));
            st.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //System.out.println(weekID);
    }//GN-LAST:event_btnAvailUpdateActionPerformed
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your database table isn't very flexible.  You have empty string values (I hope) if somebody needs to take Wednesday off.

A more flexible database table would look like this:

```
Availability
------------
Employee ID
Start Time
End Time
```

where the start time and end time are Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  The primary index of this table is (Employee ID, Start Time DESC).  This way, an employee can work two shifts on Monday and take Wednesday off.

Next, you would create Java objects to hold your database information.  In this case, you would probably need two Java objects.

The first Java object would be the Shift class.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Date;

public class Shift {

    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;

    public Shift(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

}
```

The second Java Object would be the EmployeeWorkWeek class.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeWorkWeek {

    private final int employeeID;

    private final Date mondayDate;

    private List<Shift> shifts;

    public EmployeeWorkWeek(int employeeID, Date mondayDate) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.mondayDate = mondayDate;
        this.shifts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Shift> getShifts() {
        return shifts;
    }

    public void addShift(Shift shift) {
        this.shifts.add(shift);
    }

    public void clearShifts() {
        this.shifts.clear();
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public Date getMondayDate() {
        return mondayDate;
    }

}
```

This answer is already pretty long, so I'll stop here.

First, you create the model for your application.

Second, you create the view.

Third, you create the controllers that tie the model and the view together.  In Swing, that's the action listeners and the item listeners.